# Couldn't find Portfolio with 'id'=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error message (Couldn't find Portfolio with 'id'=edit) when I try to edit my show page.

```
def set_portfolio_item
  @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
end
```

I've tried editing the id by putting edit there but it still doesn't work

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :set_portfolio_item, only: [:edit, :show, :update, :destroy]
  layout 'portfolios'
  access all: [:show, :index, :angular], user: {except: [:destroy, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :sort]},site_admin: :all

  def index 
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.by_position

    @page_title = "Portfolios"

  end

  def sort
    params[:order].each do |key, value|
      Portfolio.find(value[:id]).update(position: value[:position])
    end

    render json: { status: "updated" }
  end

  def new
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new
    3.times { @portfolio_item.technologies.build }   
  end


  def create
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'Your portfolio item is now live.'}
      else
        format.html { render :new }      
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(portfolio_params)
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record successfully updated.' }
      else   
        format.html { render :edit }  
      end
    end
  end

  def show 
  end

  def destroy
    #this going to perform the look up
    # Destroy/delete the record
    @portfolio_item.destroy

    # Redirect
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to portfolios_url, notice: 'Post was removed.' }
    end
  end

  private

  def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(
      :title, 
      :subtitle, 
      :body,
      :main_image, 
      :thumb_image,
      technologies_attributes: [:name]
    )    
  end

  def set_portfolio_item
    @portfolio_item = Portfolio.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

when clicking on `http://localhost:3000/portfolios/edit`, I expected to go to the show edit page, but getting

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PortfoliosController#show
>   Couldn't find Portfolio with 'id'=edit

this is my routes for show

```
portfolios_show GET    /portfolios/:id(.:format)                                                                portfolios#show
                     blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                                                                     blogs#show
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)    

                      active_storage/disk#show
```

this is my route for edit

```
edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                                                                 devise/passwords#edit
   edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)                                                                          devise/registrations#edit
           edit_portfolio GET    /portfolios/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           portfolios#edit
                edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                blogs#edit
```

Comment: Seems like a route problem. What do your routes look like? Is `portfolios` a `resource`?

Comment: Please post your corresponding routes, looks like there's `resources` instead of `resource`

Comment: i added in the post. I'm new coder so i think this is what you were asking for?

Comment: Why is this on -1...? The questioner has stated they're new and provided as much info as they can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click on http://localhost:3000/portfolios/edit, I can error message
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PortfoliosController#show Couldn't find Portfolio with 'id'=edit
> ```

If you want to edit a portfolio, you must supply an id, like so http://localhost:3000/portfolios/1/edit. Your current URL can only be interpreted as portfolios#show, with "edit" being the `:id` part of the route.

Comment: wow. thanks man. Oh ok it will not show nothing without telling it which id(item) i would like to edit. 10-4